# Is there any data on the average IQ of American immigrants?

Tags: united-states, immigration

And an estimate on which way and how fast it is shifting national IQ, if possible.

Comment: any estimation of shifting effects would also have to consider their children, so probably not straightforward. Also IQ is normalized to the population; there's a Flynn effect etc.

Comment: See https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/10297/is-the-average-iq-still-100 for the latter discussion.

Comment: and if you came here because of a certain alt-right discourse... that one is almost certainly based on low quality research, to put it mildly: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41802/drop-in-iq-due-to-immigration I'm pretty skeptical that there is any good/serious research on this.

Comment: That's a shame, it seems like it would be very important to know.

Comment: hrm there's a Harvard PhD thesis https://www.gwern.net/docs/iq/2009-richwine.pdf I don't really have the time to look into it rgiht now, but perhaps there's some quality research. Wikipedia says it's controversial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Richwine

Comment: And more on Richwine's thesis controversy: https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/05/08/jason-richwine-dissertation_n_3240168.html So I doubt it's too useful to answer your question.

Comment: You might want to look at https://doi.org/10.1017/S0021932014000480, but it doesn't try isolate the US. Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heiner_Rindermann it seems less controversial.

Comment: On the other hand, his co-author posts on the Unz Review, http://www.unz.com/jthompson/rindermann-supplies-cognitive-capitalism-appendixes-free/ so that makes me skeptical, given the lower-quality stuff published there.

Comment: N.B. Some follow-up (or rather fallout) of the Richwine affair: https://www.economist.com/democracy-in-america/2013/05/14/the-richwine-affair

Comment: I downvoted this question because I don't think it is useful. All an IQ test tells you about the qualities of a person is how good that person is at solving IQ test puzzles.

Comment: @hugbubby 'very important to know'? Why? I'm struggling to see a reason why it would matter, never mind be 'very important'.

Comment: Also see https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41802/drop-in-iq-due-to-immigration

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of data-based answer, let me quote you this bit from [an article](https://www.economist.com/democracy-in-america/2013/05/14/the-richwine-affair) (in The Economist) that covered the "Richwine affair"; for background, in 2009 Richwine wrote--as his Harvard PhD thesis--one the few works in recent times that tried to answer your question, i.e. IQ and immigration to the US:

> I don't think the subject or conclusion of Mr Richwine's dissertation is out of the bounds of reasonable discourse. Yet I think a suspicion of racism is perfectly reasonable. Grad students can choose from an infinite array of subjects. Why choose this one? Who are especially keen to discover a rational basis for public policy that discriminates along racial lines? Racists, of course. Anyone who chooses this subject, and comes down on the side vindicating racist assumptions, volunteers to bring suspicion upon himself, to expose his work to an extraordinary level of scrutiny. Were Mr Richwine's dissertation a model of scientific rigour, he might easily enough survive this scrutiny. However, according to Daniel Drezner, a political scientist at Tufts, it's not exemplary work:
>
> > I've perused parts of Richwine's dissertation, and … well … hoo boy. Key terms are poorly defined, auxiliary assumptions abound, and the literature I'm familiar with that is cited as authoritative is, well, not good. It's therefore unsurprising that, until last week, Richwine's dissertation disappeared into the ether the moment after it was approved. According to Google Scholar, no one cited it in the four years since it appeared. Furthermore, Richwine apparently didn't convert any part of it into any kind of refereed or non-refereed publication.
>
> [...]
>
> I suspect that Mr Richwine may have been able to survive either controversy taken in isolation. Had he not just argued, in an extremely tendentious fashion, that Hispanic immigrants are, on the whole, parasites, he might have endured public criticism of his dissertation. Had he not in his dissertation argued that Hispanic immigration ought to be limited on grounds of inferior Hispanic intelligence, he would have endured the firestorm over the risible Heritage immigration study, as Mr Rector did. Taken together, however, these two works produce a strong impression of hostility to Hispanics—they're parasitical because they're a bit dim as a breed, you see—which would be very hard to dispel. It's easy to see why Heritage let Mr Richwine dangle.

So, as you can see, the topic of IQ and immigration to the US is extremely close to simply being a rehash of the debate of [race and intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_intelligence); okay the former involves mostly Hispanics, not blacks... but otherwise is troubled by the same issues. And also related is the [nations and IQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nations_and_intelligence) theme, also studied by a small number of researchers, some with [horribly obvious biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Lynn#Controversial_statements).

Answer (score 0):

Based on past results it would certainly worsen national IQ -- ***BUT:***

Prior results demonstrating the low IQs of immigrants, mountain folk, *et al.* are based on the work of well-funded but biased and mediocre researchers who employed erroneous methods.  Their incorrect results happened to dovetail beautifully with the racist politics of wealthy sponsors providing incessant funding, thus institutionally legitimizing these erroneous results to the point of making a profession of it.

For instance:  in the early 20th century US researchers might herd into a windowless room some terrified Italian farmer just off the boat, who couldn't speak English, had never held a pencil, and unto him administer a battery of *"what's missing"* tests -- for example showing a line drawing of a tennis match with players slicing a ball, but the tennis rackets are missing.  The farmer has never even seen a tennis court, but the researchers' underlings are not instructed to consider such niceties, and therefore the farmer is scored quite low.  (If the researchers were being tested with *what's missing* tests showing details of agriculture or fishing, they'd probably score low too, but that's not the direction the funding ran and never has been.)

So, to answer the question practically, *"Down"*, though the data is of poor quality, and if there still isn't enough of it, some affluent racist, or opportunistic exploiter, or heir of a remunerative *status quo*, will happily collect and fund adequately careless researchers to provide more.

It's an ancient problem. See *Aesop's* [*The Lion and the Statue*](https://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Aesop/Aesops_Fables/The_Lion_and_the_Statue_p1.html).